# Network Response Timed Out. No funciona conexión entre Expo Go y Expo CLI

Tags: windows, react-native, expo, wsl

Estoy usando Windows 11 con Ubuntu WSL2. Esto sucede cuando ejecuto el programa de React Native con expo, npm start y escaneo el codigo QR con Expo GO en mi celular Android. Ya cree nuevas reglas de entrada y salida desde el Firewall desde los puertos 19000-19010.

---

Cuando lo ejecuto en mi Notebook con Ubuntu funciona todo correctamente pero en Windows WSL2 no

[image: Esta es la descripcion del error][image: Esto es lo primero que sale]